# vb.NET - Transferred my console application code to windows forms and I need some tweaks to display the result

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I have coded a few programs in console applications for my college projects but now I need to use windows forms to display my results properly. I transferred my console code over, took out the `console.writeline(s)` and `console.readline(s)`, instead I saved the input from a textbox using:

```
Dim SoundexString As String = StringInput.Text
```

Anyway, my code outputted fine in console and I have managed to get other things to output in windows forms using '`messagebox.show(xxx)` and '`textbox.text = xxx`'. For some reason my current code just won't output the final variable "SoundexCode"... I would be grateful for any advice. Code Below:

```
Public Class Form1

Public Sub ButtonConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonConvert.Click

    Dim SoundexString As String = StringInput.Text

    Dim SoundexCode(5) As Char
    For i = 1 To 5
        SoundexCode(i) = "0"
    Next

    GetSoundex(SoundexString, SoundexCode)
    MessageBox.Show(SoundexCode)


End Sub

Function GetSoundex(ByVal SoundexString As String, ByRef SoundexCode() As Char)

    Dim StringLength As Integer = Len(SoundexString)
    Dim LetterArray(StringLength) As Char

    'Soundex arrays to check each rule before creating soundex code
    Dim SoundexNumbers(StringLength) As Char
    Dim DoubleLetters(StringLength) As Char
    Dim ConsonantVowel(StringLength) As Char

    'Assigning Number Locations to Individual Letters, Each Letter is in Correct Position
    For i = 1 To StringLength
        LetterArray(i) = CChar(SoundexString(i - 1))
    Next

    '1. Soundex Letters into Numbers
    GetSoundexNumbers(LetterArray, SoundexNumbers, StringLength)

    '2. Names with Double Letters / Double Soundex Numbers
    RemoveDuplicateLetters(LetterArray, DoubleLetters, StringLength, SoundexNumbers)

    '3. Consonant Vowel Seperation
    SeperateConsonantVowel(LetterArray, StringLength, SoundexNumbers, ConsonantVowel)

    '4. Creating Soundex 
    GetSoundexCode(LetterArray, StringLength, SoundexNumbers, DoubleLetters, ConsonantVowel, SoundexCode)

    Return SoundexCode

End Function

Function GetSoundexNumbers(ByVal LetterArray() As Char, ByRef SoundexNumbers() As Char, ByVal StringLength As Integer)

    For i = 1 To StringLength
        SoundexNumbers(i) = LetterArray(i)
    Next

    For i = 1 To StringLength
        Select Case SoundexNumbers(i)
            Case "b", "f", "p", "v", "B", "F", "P", "V"
                SoundexNumbers(i) = "1"
            Case "c", "g", "j", "k", "q", "s", "x", "z", "C", "G", "J", "K", "Q", "S", "X", "Z"
                SoundexNumbers(i) = "2"
            Case "d", "t", "D", "T"
                SoundexNumbers(i) = "3"
            Case "l", "L"
                SoundexNumbers(i) = "4"
            Case "m", "M", "n", "N"
                SoundexNumbers(i) = "5"
            Case "r", "R"
                SoundexNumbers(i) = "6"
                'Unwanted Cases - Vowels / Phonetic Vowels
            Case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "h", "w", "y", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "H", "W", "Y"
                SoundexNumbers(i) = "!"
        End Select
    Next

    Return SoundexNumbers

End Function

Function RemoveDuplicateLetters(ByVal LetterArray() As Char, ByRef DoubleLetters() As Char, ByVal StringLength As Integer, ByVal SoundexNumbers() As Char)

    For i = 1 To StringLength
        DoubleLetters(i) = LetterArray(i)
    Next

    'Checking Double Letters

    For i = 1 To StringLength
        If i < StringLength Then
            If DoubleLetters(i) = DoubleLetters(i + 1) Then
                DoubleLetters(i + 1) = "!"
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Checking Double Soundex Numbers
    For i = 1 To StringLength
        If i < StringLength Then
            If SoundexNumbers(i) = SoundexNumbers(i + 1) Then
                DoubleLetters(i + 1) = "!"
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return DoubleLetters
End Function

Function SeperateConsonantVowel(ByVal LetterArray() As Char, ByVal StringLength As Integer, ByVal SoundexNumbers() As Char, ByRef ConsonantVowel() As Char)

    For i = 1 To StringLength
        ConsonantVowel(i) = LetterArray(i)
    Next

    'Checking that a Vowel does not have Letters both Sides which Share same Soundex Number
    For i = 1 To StringLength
        If i > 1 And i < StringLength Then
            If ConsonantVowel(i) = "a" Or ConsonantVowel(i) = "e" Or ConsonantVowel(i) = "i" Or ConsonantVowel(i) = "o" Or ConsonantVowel(i) = "u" Or ConsonantVowel(i) = "A" Or ConsonantVowel(i) = "E" Or ConsonantVowel(i) = "I" Or ConsonantVowel(i) = "O" Or ConsonantVowel(i) = "U" Then
                If SoundexNumbers(i - 1) = SoundexNumbers(i + 1) Then
                    ConsonantVowel(i - 1) = "!"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return ConsonantVowel

End Function

Function GetSoundexCode(ByVal LetterArray() As Char, ByVal StringLength As Integer, ByVal SoundexNumbers() As Char, ByVal DoubleLetters() As Char, ByVal ConsonantVowel() As Char, ByRef SoundexCode() As Char)

    SoundexCode(1) = LetterArray(1)
    SoundexCode(2) = "-"

    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim CounterStore As Integer

    For Counter = 2 To StringLength
        If SoundexNumbers(Counter) <> "!" And DoubleLetters(Counter) <> "!" And ConsonantVowel(Counter) <> "!" Then
            SoundexCode(3) = SoundexNumbers(Counter)
            CounterStore = Counter
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If CounterStore < StringLength Then
        For Counter = CounterStore + 1 To StringLength
            If SoundexNumbers(Counter) <> "!" And DoubleLetters(Counter) <> "!" And ConsonantVowel(Counter) <> "!" Then
                SoundexCode(4) = SoundexNumbers(Counter)
                CounterStore = Counter
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf CounterStore = StringLength Then
        SoundexCode(4) = "0"
        SoundexCode(5) = "0"
    End If

    If CounterStore < StringLength Then
        For Counter = CounterStore + 1 To StringLength
            If SoundexNumbers(Counter) <> "!" And DoubleLetters(Counter) <> "!" And ConsonantVowel(Counter) <> "!" Then
                SoundexCode(5) = SoundexNumbers(Counter)
                CounterStore = Counter
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf CounterStore = StringLength Then
        SoundexCode(5) = "0"
    End If

    Return SoundexCode
End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are 0-based arrays (first letter starts at index 0) but SoundexCode is a 1-based array (ie. index 0 is null) so when it's converted to a string, SoundexCode appears as an empty string.

To fix your code, just use the String(value As Char(), startIndex As Integer, length As Integer) constructor instead of the regular one.

ie.
    MessageBox.Show(New String(SoundexCode, 1, 5))